# How can I change return view type from <TupleView<(View, View)>> to <_> for initialization?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that return a view in form of `<TupleView<(View, View)>>`, like this:
[image]

Also I have a view that return a view in form of `<_>`, like this:
[image]

With knowing that both way works and my wished way is using **TupleView** under cover but having the look of `<_>`, I tried to work on **MyView3**, as you can see in my tried codes I want this look of `(content: () -> _) -> MyView3<_>` for being more simple and understandable, but i need TupleView way initialization undercover. I got 3 error's for **MyView3** to make it work. Do you think is there a way for my goal?

For more information see this codes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        MyView1(content: {
            Text("Text 1").fixedSize()
            Text("Text 2").fixedSize()
        })
            .padding()

        MyView2(tupleViewContent: {
            Text("Text 3").fixedSize()
            Text("Text 4").fixedSize()
        })
            .padding()

        // This part has issue!
        MyView3(content: {
            Text("Text 5").fixedSize()
            Text("Text 6").fixedSize()
        })
            .padding()

    }
}

struct MyView1<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}

struct MyView2<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: () -> Content
    
    init<Content1: View, Content2: View>(@ViewBuilder tupleViewContent: @escaping () -> Content) where Content == TupleView<(Content1, Content2)> {
        self.content = tupleViewContent
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}

struct MyView3<Content: View>: View {

    let content: () -> Content

    private init<Content1: View, Content2: View>(@ViewBuilder tupleViewContent: @escaping () -> Content) where Content == TupleView<(Content1, Content2)> {
         self.content = tupleViewContent
    }
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        
        //Error:
        // Generic parameter 'Content1' could not be inferred
        // Generic parameter 'Content2' could not be inferred
        // Initializer 'init(tupleViewContent:)' requires the types 'Content' and 'TupleView<(Content1, Content2)>' be equivalent
        self.init(tupleViewContent: content)
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generics is resolved at compilation time, so init/s should go from more specific to more common (finally to the designated one).

In your case it should be like (tested with Xcode 13.2)

```
struct MyView3<Content: View>: View {

    let content: () -> Content

    init<Content1: View, Content2: View>(@ViewBuilder tupleViewContent: @escaping () -> Content) where Content == TupleView<(Content1, Content2)> {
         self.init(content: tupleViewContent)
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed the tupleView way initialization be private, do you think it is possible?

Comment: It is useless private, because swift compiler try to resolve needed initialiser at the time of compilation of client of this api, not in runtime, or internally, so it needs to have same visibility as any init.